# Using named streams with clis without support for stdin

Tags: node.js, bash, stream, stdin, child-process

I'm using the following code to read a pdf from web and pass to pdftotext without saving it in the local file system:

```
const source = 'http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//archive/gfs-sosp2003.pdf'
const http = require('http')
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn

download(source).then(pdftotext)
.then(result => console.log(result.slice(0, 77)))

function download(url) {
  return new Promise(resolve => http.get(url, resolve))
}

function pdftotext(binaryStream) {
  //read input from stdin and write to stdout
  const command = spawn('pdftotext', ['-', '-'])
  binaryStream.pipe(command.stdin)

  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const result = []
    command.stdout.on('data', chunk => result.push(chunk.toString()))
    command.stdout.on('end', () => resolve(result.join('')))
  })
}
```

In this example, it will work because the pdftotext supports stdin, but if wasn't the case, what could i do? I write about named streams, but didn't found anything about it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the environment provides `/dev/fd/0` or `/dev/stdin` you can use those, but it's not entirely portable.

Comment: Could you explain better this solution?

Comment: What's to explain?  If a command requires a file name argument, that's a file name which refers to the standard input stream, e.g. on Linux and Mac OSX.  Some older platforms didn't support it.

Comment: Hmmm, this is interesting, i will try.

Comment: If i understood correctly, the only change needed in this code would be ```spawn('pdftotext', ['/dev/stdin', '-']), is this correct? Thanks!!!

Comment: That's the idea, yeah (though I don't speak Node, so not sure about the syntax).  Of course, if the command you are trying to spawn doesn't take a file name arguent at all, this won't work.  Some silly tools have hard-coded output paths (`a.out` is a classic, although of course you can override that) or -- even worse -- hard-coded input paths.

Comment: Doesn't work :/.. the output is blank.

Comment: I have answered your question.  [The manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pdftotext) suggests that you don't need to supply any parameters at all in order to have the program read standard input and write to standard output; I'm guessing maybe you will find a file named `-` in the directory where you ran this, but this is far out of scope for this site already.